# WSO2 ESB and Registry Governance integration

Tags: wsdl, wso2, integration, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

I am trying to publish a WSDL in the Governance Registry through the publish app of the GREG. 
I have a problem with the endpoints of th wsdl.

The imported endpoint isn't usable from ESB. When I call the proxy service with this endpoint I obtain this error: ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Invalid endpoint configuration. {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}

This behaviour does not make sense for me. The integration between ESB and GREG should be useful to use previously GREG imported endpoint and wsdl when creating proxies. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK that are 2 different endpoints.

Comment: Hi, but in previous version (4.8.0) of GREG the endpoint was of synapse type (not of metadata type). In my opinion it's useless. or not? Thanks

Comment: How can I use resources imported into Governance Registry? I explain my idea: I would like to import a wsdl of a service and obtain an endpoint's reference (Apache Synapse endpoint). I would like use this endpoint in the ESB. It's wrong?Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the endpoint generated by GREG when publishing a WSLD is a kind of "catalog porpouse" artifact rather than an ESB artifact. You can check this just having a look to the XML code of the ESB endpoint and GREG endpoint.

Best Regards

Comment: Hi, but in previous version (4.8.0) of GREG the endpoint was of synapse type (not of metadata type). In my opinion it's useless. or not? Thanks

Comment: How can I use resources imported into Governance Registry? I explain my idea: I would like to import a wsdl of a service and obtain an endpoint's reference (Apache Synapse endpoint). I would like use this endpoint in the ESB. It's wrong?Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way? Thanks

Comment: Hi, the only way to share resources with esb is placing them in the governance registry (system\governance) in GREG. Whatever you place there can be referenced from all WSO2 components (if they are configured properly). About whether the endponts are useless or not, I agree the are useless for ESB. As I said before I think it is only for "catalog porpouse". A reason for this, may be that it would be hard, or even risky, to generate a endpoint compatible with all esb/components version and with a proper specific configuration like security, certificates,....

Answer (score 0):

Please find [this](https://cnapagoda.blogspot.com/2016/05/g-reg-and-esb-integration-scenarios-for.html) useful article about G-Reg and ESB integration. This is a generic concept which will not be bounded to specific version of WSO2 product.